# svn backup bash script errors

Tags: bash, subversion

I have created bash script for create dump of svn repositories. I want to add such functionality that after dump of every repository script send it to remote server using rsync and delete from dump location and after that starts to make dump of next repository. I am using following script.

script has some errors help me to improve it.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Record todays date
# --------------------
bakdate=$(date +%Y%m%d)
echo "--------------------------------"
echo "Running SVN backup $bakdate"
echo "--------------------------------\n"

# From where to backup repos?
# ---------------------------
svnrepos="/kk/svn/"
echo "\nGoing to backup all SVN repos located at: $svnrepos \n"

# Where to save the dump?
# ------------------------
bakdest="/save/"

# Location of remote server (to copy backup)
# ----------------------------------------
baktoremote="root@192.168.11.156:/kk"

   cd $svnrepos


# Just make sure we have write access to backup-folder
if [ -d "$bakdest" ] && [ -w "$bakdest" ] ; then
  # Now $repo has folder names = project names
  for repo in *; do
    # do svn dump for each project
    echo "Taking backup/svndump for: $repo"
    echo "Executing : svnadmin dump $repo >
$bakdest/$repo-$bakdate.dump \n"
    # Now finally execute the backup
    svnadmin dump $repo > $bakdest/$repo-$bakdate.dump


# Just make sure we have write access to backup-folder
if [ -d "$bakdest" ] && [ -w "$bakdest" ] ; then
  # Now $repo has folder names = project names
  for repo in *; do
    # do svn dump for each project
    echo "Taking backup/svndump for: $repo"
    echo "Executing : svnadmin dump $repo >
$bakdest/$repo-$bakdate.svn.dump \n"
    # Now finally execute the backup
    svnadmin dump $repo > $bakdest/$repo-$bakdate.dump

    # sent it to remote server 

 rsync -avP $bakdest/$repo-$bakdate.dump $baktoremote



  # delete repository after sending  

    rm -rf $repo-$bakdate.dump

    fi
```

Comment: ./backup.sh: line 55: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./backup.sh: line 55: `    fi'

Comment: I am also getting error after adding fi

Comment: ./backup: line 55: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./backup: line 55: `    fi '

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8377/discussion-between-k-k-patel-and-slm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End your if blocks with `fi`

End your loops with `done`

Each `if` must be matched by one `fi`, and each `do` must be matched by one `done`.